# Why is there a 'None' value after handling an exception?

Tags: python, exception, nonetype

I've tried running this simple code in an attempt to handle the ZeroDivisionError exception

```
def test(n):
    try:
        return 10 / n
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print('Can\'t divide by 0')

print(test(0))
```

Output:

```
Can't divide by 0
None
```

Why is there a None value after handling the exception?

Comment: What value do you expect after handling the exception?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not returning a value from your function.

The exception is thrown by the expression `10 / n` that is evaluated before the return statement.
Therefore, the return statement is never executed.

You must define what your function shall return in case your exception is thrown.

Either like this:

```
def test(n):
    try:
        return 10 / n
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print('Can\'t divide by 0')
    return -1 # DIV/0 should return -1

print(test(0))
```

Or like this:

```
def test(n):
    try:
        return 10 / n
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print('Can\'t divide by 0')
        return -1 # DIV/0 should return -1

print(test(0))
```

See: https://onlinegdb.com/By2AVSvEv

Comment: I was under the impression the output of the 'except' statement is the return value of the function. Thank you for your answer I get it now that the function nonetheless need to return a value after running the 'except statement